# Better way to enforce category hierarchy in post_categories_metabox?

Tags: taxonomy, filters, metabox, actions, hierarchical

The objective is to ensure that when editing a post, the metabox that lists a hierarchical taxonomy doesn't reorder itself upon Update to put checked items on top.

Right now, `edit-form-advanced.php` calls `add_meta_box()`, passing a callback of `post_categories_meta_box`, which is defined in `meta-boxes.php`.

`post_categories_meta_box()` invokes `wp_terms_checklist()`, leaving the `checked_ontop` parameter undefined. `wp_terms_checklist()` defaults that parameter to `true`, which is the root cause of all this hooplah.

Nary a filter hook to be found anywhere along the chain until we back out and discover `add_meta_boxes` and `add_meta_boxes_{$post_type}`.

The only solution I was able to come up with myself was to hook onto one of these actions, globalize `$wp_meta_boxes`, and replace occurrences of the `post_categories_meta_box` callback with a callback of my own, where I completely duplicate all of `post_categories_meta_box()` and simply add the parameter `'checked_ontop' => false`.

Works. But fugly. This seems ridiculous - is there no more elegant way to simply let your hierarchical taxonomies keep their order in metaboxes?

Answer (score 2):

There's a plugin written specifically to fix this 'feature' of WordPress, it's called [Category Checklist Tree](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-checklist-tree/). Despite the name, it works on custom taxonomies too.

Comment: Scribu's plugin, as Admirable as it is, does exactly the same thing: it duplicates the entire function, and then modifies the argument, As I described. I probably was not as clear in my original post as I should have been: the request was to find a more elegant way of achieving the objective, not for a plug-in that would help me do it, since I had already rolled my own code to accomplish that. But thanks for the link to this plug-in! There is a ton of good stuff in there: I always learn something new when I read through Scribu's code.

Comment: Your way (and scribu's) is the way to do it.  It's not fugly, it's just how it is.  That's why the WP core uses its own API (ala `add_meta_box`): so you can replace its functionality with your own.  The alternative is probably an even uglier javascript hack.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there is a hook available for this problem:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_terms_checklist_args/